# Is there any way to pass through Secure Boot and install linux?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

Is there any way to pass through Windows 8 Restricted Boot and install linux? I have Windows 8 machine with restricted boot, but I would like to use Ubuntu on the same machine. Just like Ubuntu/Windows7 configuration. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your hardware:

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Secure_boot):

> Microsoft also requires that manufacturers offer the ability to turn off the secure boot feature on x86 hardware, but they must not offer such an option on ARM hardware.

If you have a x86 architecture, you probably have an option in your boot to disable the `secure boot` feature.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no such thing has `Microsoft Restricted Boot`.  There is something called `Secure Boot` and is a required feature within a UEFI Interface Standard.  This means any UEFI Bios is required to support it, in order to call itself, a UEFI Bios.

> I have Windows 8 machine with restricted boot, but I would like to use
>   Ubuntu on the same machine. Just like Ubuntu/Windows7 configuration.
>   Is that possible?

Once Windows 8 is actually released Ubuntu will support doing exactly this.

As for requirement of not being able to disable `Secured Boot` within an Windows RT ARM device, that is entirely different, because the implementation of BIOS on an ARM isn't even UEFI Bios technically.

Comment: what was the downvote for?