# Can't use USB stick to install Ubuntu on a Toshiba L855 laptop with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I get 'boot failure:  proper digital signature was not found.  One of the files on the selected boot device was rejected by the secure boot feature.'

Is this a common problem?

Comment: First try with Secure Boot enabled and [UbuntuSecureRemix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix). If that fails disable Secure Boot as stated below.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your BIOS settings for secure boot and disable that. You should be able to enter BIOS by pressing some key (e.g. F2 - see your startup screen) at startup.

see [Is there any way to pass through Secure Boot and install linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/473225/is-there-any-way-to-pass-through-secure-boot-and-install-linux/473231#473231) for more info.